# How to wait for queries to get results while running nested mysql query in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
  connection.query('SELECT * from enquiry', function(err, rows,  fields) {
 if (err) throw err;
  var enquiryJson=[];

  for (var i in rows) {
      var id=1,jsondata,message;

        connection.query('SELECT status_message from status where id='+rows[i].status_id, function(err, statusrows, field) {
          console.log(statusrows[0].status_message);
         message=statusrows[0].status_message;

      });

          jsondata={
          "id": id++,
          "name": rows[i].name,
          "mobile": rows[i].mobile,
          "city": rows[i].city,
          "state": rows[i].state,
          "nature_of_enq": rows[i].nature_of_enq,
          "status":  message
      };

      enquiryJson.push(jsondata);
}
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.end(JSON.stringify(enquiryJson));
  });
  });
```

I am just a beginner to nodejs. I just want to know how to wait for child query to return result? in code above I am trying to set a JSON key("status") value which will be returned by child query. But I am always getting message variable as undefined. However I get the message variable in console. I think node server does not wait for child query's result. What could be the solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `aync.each` (https://github.com/caolan/async#each) and call a callback function when everything ends.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `async.each`.

The idea is that you do your first query and inside of that query you could do an synchronous process that would end only when everything ends.

You could read more here https://github.com/caolan/async#each and in your case you could start with something like this:

```
var getStatusMessage = function(row, callback){
    //Here yo do your query
    //SELECT status_message from status where id='+ row.status_id... bla bla bla
    //and you can update your json here
}

async.each(rows, getStatusMessage, function(err){
    if(err){
        //Something bad happened
    }
    //enquiryJson.push(jsondata);
    //res.setHeader
    //res.end ....
    //Wathever you wanna do after your queries ends

});
```

Comment: then how do I pass status_id?

Comment: @John, you don't need to pass the status_id, the `getStatusMessage` function will take the each row and will iterate from there. I already updated my answer in order to clarify this.